# How to get YouTube channels' topic categories in bulk with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, youtube-data-api

I have a list that contains around 10,000 YouTube channels - got it from Google Ads. I want to get each channel's topic category into a new column. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before proceeding to the code, make sure:

- You enabled YouTube Data API v3 for your Google Cloud Project and created an API key. Please see the [getting started document](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) if needed.
- Create the "importjson.gs" file for your Google Apps Script project and [paste this code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/paulgambill/cacd19da95a1421d3164/raw/047b04a1c321b697533adad5828e6df8748b5e54/import_json_appsscript.js) into it.

Once you're done with the preliminary steps, you can proceed to the following code: It creates the function `GET_CHANNEL_TOPIC_CATEGORIES`, which takes the channel URL as an input and returns the channel topic categories.

Here is the code:

```
var API_KEY='YOUR_API_KEY'
var CHANNELS_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels'

function GET_CHANNEL_TOPIC_CATEGORIES(channel_url){
    channel_id = channel_url.replace("http://youtube.com/channel/", "")
    url_uploads_id = CHANNELS_URL + "?part=topicDetails&id=" + channel_id + "&key=" + API_KEY;
    return ImportJSON(url_uploads_id, "/items/topicDetails/topicCategories", "noHeaders")
}
```